# Return Extras from Intent

Tags: android, date, android-intent

I’m having trouble returning extras from an intent. I'm sending a Date type data object and in my sending activity, I have the following;

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("SELECTED_DATE",SelectedDate);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

And in the receiving activity I have;

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
       selectedDate = new Date(data.getExtras().getLong("SELECTED_DATE"));
       displayDate(selectedDate);
   }
}
```

Regardless of what date is sent, in the receiving activity I get Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969. When I debug it the correct date values are being set in the putExtra command, and I can see the value in the mMap values for the intent. On the receiving side the intent shows "has extras" but the mMap = null.

I'm using similar code to return String types with no problem. Is there something else I need to return a Date type?

Comment: what is the mMap. Where is the mMap?

Comment: What value do you get for that long to begin with?

Comment: The only thing i think can go wrong with your code is that your `SelectedDate` type wasn't Long. so `getLong` returns null. maybe `getString` or ... helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you pass the `Date` object as an argument, you will be setting a `Serializable` extra. you need to set the extra as a `long` if you want to retrieve a `long`, so:

```
intent.putExtra("SELECTED_DATE",SelectedDate.getTime());
```

Intent has many `putExtra()` methods, the one you're using there is `putExtra(String, Serializable)`, because `Date` implements `Serializable`. When retrieving the value with a key (`"SELECTED_DATE"`), the types of the object must also be the same.

Comment: Thanks, I had read that I should pass the time as a long, but I didn’t realize that I had to use the getTime() function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

***You are passing Date object as parameter to intent and try to take it return as long***

Basically you have to send long or String and get same back in returning activity

### While sending

```
intent.putExtra("SELECTED_DATE",SelectedDate.getTime());//this return long val
```

### While receiving

```
selectedDate = new Date(data.getExtras().getLong("SELECTED_DATE"));
```